# How to use Order By clause on a column containing string values separated by comma?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, sql-order-by

I have a table with a column named `Skills` which contains comma separated values for different employees like

```
EmpID  Skills
 1     C,C++,Oracle
 2     Java,JavaScript,PHP
 3     C,C++,Oracle
 4     JavaScript,C++,ASP
 5     C,C++,JavaScript
```

So I want to write a query which will order all the employees first who knows `JavaScript`, how can I get this result?

Comment: Better to redesign the schema, if possible, to store these separate values in separate rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
    SELECT *
        ,CASE WHEN Skills LIKE '%JavaScript%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Rnk 
    FROM MyTable
) T
ORDER BY rnk,EmpID
```

[**DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/129130)

OR

```
SELECT * FROM #MyTable
ORDER BY CASE WHEN Skills LIKE '%JavaScript%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,EmpID
```

Answer (score 2):

You should **not** use one attribute to store multiple values. That goes against relation DB principles.

Instead of that you should create additional table to store skills and refer to employee in it. Then, your query will looks like:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  employees 
  LEFT JOIN employees_skills 
    ON employee.id=employees_skills.employee_id 
WHERE 
  employees_skills='JavaScript'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select EmpID, Skills
from Table1
order by case when Skills like '%JavaScript%' then 0 else 1 end
```

Comment: I want all the rows but ordered by those employees first who knows java script

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM YourTable
 ORDER BY PATINDEX('%JavaScript%', Skills) DESC
```

But this is a bad way. You should really normalize your table.

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL

```
select Skills from myTable 
order by case Skills 
when "Javascript" then 0 
when "Java" then 1 when "C++" then 2
end
```

and so on

For SQL Server

```
select Skills from myTable 
order by case 
when Skills="Javascript" then 1
when Skill="Java" then 2
else 3 
end
```

Make sure to start SQL server from 1 (That I'm not sure).
Include an else before end that will show all remaining results.

For more details about SQL Server [see this](http://chiragrdarji.wordpress.com/2008/04/04/using-case-with-order-by-in-sql-server/) or [see this](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/07/17/sql-server-case-statement-in-order-by-clause-order-by-using-variable/)

Answer (score 0):

This works for DB2/400:

```
with s (id, skill, rest) as                       
    (select id, '', sk from skills                    
     union all                                        
     select id, substr(rest, 1, locate(',',rest)-1),  
                substr(rest,locate(',',rest)+1)      
     from       s                                    
     where      locate(',',rest) > 0)                
select id, skill from s                           
where  skill = 'JavaScript'                       
order by id
```